# silverlight 4 and wcf security

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight application and a wcf that the silverlight application gets access to.  Can someone point me to an article or explain the best way to secure this wcf service and prevent other users from directly accessing the wcf (or evil silverlight programs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [good article](http://programmerpayback.com/2008/12/29/ria-security-101-logins-web-services-usernames-and-passwords/) about the web services security.

In my applications, I decided to use the session approach because it's flexible and easy to implement.